# Please check my simplification for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm hoping someone could check my work. I'm trying to simplify the equation for $x$.
$$(\frac{x}{a})^{3.2} + (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2} = 1$$
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{174.1}{86}$$
Thus I began by substituting $a$ with:
$$a = \frac{174.1}{86}b$$
$$((\frac{86}{174.1})(\frac{x}{b}))^{3.2} + (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2} = 1$$
$$((\frac{86}{174.1})(\frac{x}{b}))^{3.2} = 1 - (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2}$$
$$(\frac{x}{b})^{3.2} = \frac{(1 - (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2})(174.1)^{3.2}}{(86)^{3.2}}$$
$$x^{3.2} = \frac{(1 - (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2})(174.1)^{3.2}(b)^{3.2}}{(86)^{3.2}}$$
$$x^{3.2} = \frac{(1 - (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2})((174.1)(b))^{3.2}}{(86)^{3.2}}$$
$$x^{\frac{16}{5}} = \frac{(1 - (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2})((174.1)(b))^{3.2}}{(86)^{3.2}}$$
$$x = [\frac{(1 - (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2})((174.1)(b))^{3.2}}{(86)^{3.2}}]^{\frac{5}{16}}$$
Is my work correct, or am I completely off the board?

Comment: Right I think.  Though I would simplify it to be $x= (1-(\frac{y}{b})^{3.2})^{5/16}\frac{174.1b}{86}$

Comment: @BrianDing Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - though the result can be simplified (notice how some of your exponents cancel out). In general, if we have the equation 
$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^n=1$$

We have the solution for $x$ as

$$x=a\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Now if you want, you can use the equation $\dfrac{a}{b}=c$ to write this as

$$x=bc\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

EDIT: As you point out we can make this even simpler by doing

$$x=bc\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=bc\left(\frac{b^n-y^n}{b^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=c(b^n-y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Thank you! I've redone my work using your suggestion and it is much simpler.

Comment: Could this be an answer as well?   
Let $\frac{a}{b}=c$  
$$x = c(b - y^{3.2})^{\frac{5}{16}}$$

Comment: @Acharya Almost, I think it should actually be $$(b^{3.2}-y^{3.2})^{\frac{5}{16}}\left(\frac{174.1}{86}\right)$$

Comment: @Acharya That is we can write $$x=bc\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ $$=bc\left(\frac{b^n-y^n}{b^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ $$=c(b^n-y^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I get:

$$x=\frac{1}{273504080000}*a^{\frac{1}{5}}*(273504080000a^3-5277112021*2^{{\frac{3}{5}}}*215^{\frac{4}{5}}*1741^{\frac{1}{5}}*y^3*({\frac{y}{a}})^{{\frac{1}{5}}})$$